# Deciding whether a graph admits a nontrivial star-stabiliser

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, computational-complexity

I'm interested to find out the complexity of the following problem:

Given a finite simplicial (unoriented, with no loops and multiple edges) graph $\Gamma = (V\Gamma, E\Gamma)$, decide whether or not there exists $v \in V\Gamma$ such that $\mathop{stab}(B(1,v)) \leq \mathop{Aut}(\Gamma)$, the stabliser of the ball of radius (with respect to the path metric) centred around $v$, is non-trivial.

We assume that the graph $\Gamma$ is presented on input as a list of vertices and edges.

Comment: Start with a graph $G$, then add a new vertex $v$ adjacent to all vertices in $G$. Call this new graph $G'$. The stabiliser of the ball around $v$ in $G'$ is non-trivial if and only if $G$ has non-trivial automorphisms. So the complexity of your problem is equivalent to the complexity of determining whether a graph has non-trivial symmetry. I'm not sure, but I would guess the latter is equivalent to determining the automorphism group. (This might be known.) In particular, the complexity is probably unknown, but at most quasipolynomial.

Comment: Thanks @verret (Hi Gabe!) for the comment. So it seems that my problem, let's call it star-problem, is at least as hard the graph automorphism (GA) problem. And at the same time, graph isomorphism problem is at least as hard GA problem. It's not conclusive, but it's a good indication that star-problem will most likely be at most quasipolynomial as you say.